# Is using short in C a bad practice

Tags: c, int, short

I have a memory sensitive project that uses ints to store an index of a vertex in a dense predecessor tree of a graph. (something that you generate using e.g. Bellman Ford). I know for a fact that I won't be having graphs with more than 10000 vertices, and the datatype is immutable, once created.

So is it a bad practice in my case to replace

```
int predecessors[blah];
```

with

```
short predecessors[blah];
```

if my work is to be used as a library.

Comment: I'd say you should `typedef short vertex_id_t;` to be able to replace the type easily. Otherwise, as long as it provides a real performance/memory consumption improvement, I see no problem with it.

Comment: It's a bad practice to look for best practices as a substitute for common sense.

Comment: Sorry for my overlapping edit. I thought that you are clearly asking about C++, because you mention that language in the title. Please [edit] and make title and tags agree.

Comment: @PSkocik, in an OOP language, I'd simply hide this detail. In a language without implicit casts, I'd rely on a type checker. C makes this decision tougher.

Comment: @Yunnosch, good catch, thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. If you have to undo the same edit to your questions twice, by different people, then I recommend starting to think about why your questions seems to invite that edit... (I admit I only realised the previous iteration of edit+undo after you undid mine.)

Comment: Sizes of`short*` and `int*` are exactly the same size, size of pointer. Are you talking about changing the data type stored in an array, or what? Please clarify! Changing pointer type does not magically change what the pointer points to, it is the other way around, pointer type must match what is actually stored.

Comment: If you want to limit the width to 16 bits for counts, use `uint16_t` (or `int16_t` if you need -1 as some kind of marker and 0xFFFF won't do).

Comment: @hyde - pointers to different types are not guaranteed to be the same size.  In practice, on most modern hardware, they are, but it's not something you can rely on to be true everywhere all the time.

Comment: In general, the answer to a question "Is it a bad practice to use *X*", where X is an integral part of the language, is "No, it depends".

Comment: @JohnBode Can you find an architecture, where plain `short*` and `int*` data pointers would have different size? But yeah, your nitpick is still correct.

Comment: @hyde: I've yet to encounter such an architecture myself, and it's the longest of shots that any of us would.  But I spent the 90s writing code that had to run on multiple platforms and repeatedly got bit by platform-specific weirdness, so I'm extra-aware of things that the language *doesn't* guarantee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Avoid premature optimization. Measure the impact of using `short` instead of `int` then decide based on that information.
2. As **@HolyBlackCat** said - consider using a typedef (or similar) so you can change the underlying type (i.e. `short` to `int`) in the event of changing requirements.
3. If you are using `short`, add sanity checks to avoid someone, someday feeding 100.000 vertices in your library and not realizing it cannot handle those (until a silent failure turns into a very non-silent one by expensive equipment loudly crashing into something).
4. Clearly document that you can only handle up to **X** number of vertices.